# DOM traversal using jquery with li element

Tags: jquery, dom

All,

I have the following code

```
<ul class="known-fields list-unstyled" [hidden]='!showKnownList' style="width: 25%; max-height: 400px">
    <li class="known-field known-field-hover" *ngFor="let knownField of knownFields" (click)="onKnownFieldClicked($event, knownField)">
        <span class="known-field-text" [ngClass]="{ 'required': knownField.required }">
            {{ knownField.label }}
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I know the current element but am having problems getting the parent of the  element to remove the click event.

This shows me the correct span element

```
console.log($(this.activeKnownFieldElement).html());
```

This shows me EVERY li element in the loop.  I would think parent() would just show me a SINGLE li element right above the  element (so I can remove the click event).

```
console.log($(this.activeKnownFieldElement).parent().html());
```

What am I missing?

Thx
jonpfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line should simply be:

```
console.log($(this.activeKnownFieldElement).parent());
```

[`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) alone will give you the parent element. [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) returns exactly what its name implies: the innerHTML of the element, which means all of the elements and subtrees.